# Embeddable rings axiomatic class?

Tags: ring-theory, model-theory

In this question, a ring is defined to be with a unit distinct from the zero element, not necessarily a commutative ring though. Is the class of all such rings that can be embedded into fields an axiomatizable class? If so, what are the axioms?

Comment: Are "fields" commutative?

Comment: Yes, yes they are.

Comment: @user107952: not so in French mathematical parlance.

Comment: The bit about noncommutativity isn't necessary then, since subrings of fields are all commutative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, such rings are exactly the integral domains, i.e. the rings which are commutative and in which $xy=0$ implies either $x=0$ or $y=0$.  Any field is an integral domain (if $xy=0$ and $x\neq 0$, you can multiply by $x^{-1}$ to get $y=0$) and clearly any subring of an integral domain is an integral domain, so any ring that embeds in a field is an integral domain.  Conversely, given an integral domain, it is a subring of its [field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions).

Comment: Re: commutativity, if we look at division rings it's not at all obvious to me that any division ring without zero divisors embeds into a division ring - is this actually the case? If not, do you know if the relevant class of rings is first-order definable?

Comment: My understanding is that not every noncommutative ring without zero divisors embeds into a division ring; I don't know whether subrings of division rings are first-order axiomatizable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you can find an example of a domain which does not embed in any division ring appears in *Lectures on modules and rings* by Lam in the chapter on noncommutative localization

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks!